# After update Woocommerce shop page not showing products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, frontpage

I have assigned shop page as my Static front page from `"Settings > Reading"` and it working fine. But yesterday I have update WooCommerce Plugin to new version and after that my home page not display products. it show header, footer and sidebar but not showing content products.

I have checked in to my code and checked that there is condition I have apply `if (have_post()) {}` but code not execute in to this condition. and it is going to to `else` part saying "This is no products" but there is 12 products.

Further I checked with inspect element and fount that in body classed there is page id = 0 `class="page-id-0"` instead of its page id like `class="page-id-43"`

Can anyone look in to this I have many solutions but no luck. Thanks!

Comment: in wp-config.php file on the root, change WP_DEBUG to true and see if you get any error meesage

Comment: yes I have already done this but no error display